# jQuery fn to pause HTML 5 video broken on flash fallback

Tags: jquery, html, video, detection

I have a small jQuery .click function that I intend to use as a way to skip an HTML5 video, and start a photo slideshow in it's place. Here it is below:

```
$("a.skip").click(function () {
    $("div.vidbox video").hide();                   
    $("div.vidbox div").hide();
    $(".slideshow").fadeIn(1000, function () {setInterval( "slideSwitch()", 5000 )});
    $("div.vidbox video").get(0).pause();
    return false;
});
```

Which is to work with the following markup:

```
<video width="1000" height="400" preload="auto" controls="controls" poster="a/i/pe_home_poster.jpg" style="display: none;">
    <source src="a/v/pre-launch-welcome-video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    <source src="a/v/pre-launch-welcome-video.ogg" type="video/ogg" />
    <object id="flowplayer" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="1000" height="400">
        <param name="movie" value="a/flowplayer/flowplayer-3.2.7-0.swf" /> 
        <param name="flashvars" 
            value='config={"clip":"http://www.clientsite.com/a/v/pre-launch-welcome-video.mp4"}' />                 
        <embed type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="1000" height="400" 
            src="a/flowplayer/flowplayer-3.2.7-0.swf"
            flashvars='config={"clip":"http://www.clientsite.com/a/v/pre-launch-welcome-video.mp4"}'/>  
    </object>               
</video>
```

However, the problem is that when the browser falls back to the flash-based player, the pause function returns undefined, and breaks the script.

Right now, I have mitigated the effects by having the call to the pause function near the bottom of the click function, so only the return fails, but I think I can do better.

What I would like to take away from this is either how I can make the line conditional, and/or how to detect which video is actually playing using jQuery. Thanks to anyone with comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could test to see if the browser supports video

```
var supportsVideo = !!(document.createElement('video').canPlayType);

if (supportsVideo) {
$("div.vidbox video").get(0).pause();
}
```

Comment: That worked!
Thank you kindly! I like this trick. I won't forget it.

Comment: If you need to do more testing of browser features, make sure you check out Modernizer http://www.modernizr.com/